# GWT RequestFactory - adding custom methods to proxy classes?

Tags: java, gwt, requestfactory

Is is possible to add a method to GWT RequestFactory's proxy class? Let's say I have this:

```
@ProxyFor(value = MyEntity.class)
interface MyEntityProxy extends EntityProxy {
  String getData(); // got it on server side
}
```

`GetData()` is backed at server side, that's fine. What if I'd like to add a method like this:

```
@ProxyFor(value = MyEntity.class)
interface MyEntityProxy extends EntityProxy {
  String getData(); // got it on server side
  String getDataAndAppendQwerty(); // want this one on client side
}
```

I want to manually implement `getDataAndAppendQwerty()`. It's 100% client-side code and the question is just where should I put the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be [AutoBean categories](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean#Categories), but they're [not (yet)](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/IkoTd85mvas/discussion) surfaced in RequestFactory.

Comment: Or should we just wait for Java 8 support?

Comment: No update. And I'm not sure how "default methods" work with AutoBean and RequestFactory; pretty sure they'll just blow out; maybe try with a GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT? (not sure it supports default methods yet)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way. You could use a wrapper and delegate

```
public class MyEntityProxyExt implements MyEntityProxy {

  private final MyEntityProxy proxy;

  public MyEntityProxyExt(MyEntityProxy proxy) {
      this.proxy = proxy;
  }

  @Override
  public String getData() {

      return proxy.getData();
  }

  public Object getDataAndAppendQwerty() {

      return proxy.getData() + "qwerty";
  }
}
```

but you'd have to manually wrap all your proxy objects on the client when you get them back from the server.